# Custom Icomparer in Linq to Objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List.

Where T is a class have properties like int and other parameters

E.g.

```
  ID Name

  1  Apple
  2  Banana
  3  Test
```

Now i have another List which specify order

```
Like 2,1,3
```

So i want to sort them using 2,1,3 like Banana,Apple and then Test

How can i implement this wihh IComaparer

Currently i tries this but it failed

```
 test = test.OrderBy(p=>  SortableIntList.Contains(p.ID));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quickly get it working,

```
test = test
    .Where(p => SortableIntList.Contains(p.ID))
    .OrderBy(p => SortableIntList.IndexOf(p.ID));
```

To make it more efficient, you may want to store your sort order in a dictionary (ID => position) and then call it like

```
var SortableIntDictionary = SortableIntList
    .Select((ID, Index) => new { ID, Index })
    .ToDictionary(p => p.ID, p => p.Index);
test = test
    .Where(p => SortableIntDictionary.ContainsKey(p.ID))
    .OrderBy(p => SortableIntDictionary[p.ID]);
```

Comment: @Moons Actually... \@TommyGroves has a better solution for this, I feel.

Comment: Your second dictionary solution gives me error i am not sure why "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

Comment: It shouldn't do, it checks the key is there before it tries to use it :-/

Comment: This is what i wrote:  var SortableIntDictionary = OrderedClient.Select((ID, Index) => new { ID, Index }).ToDictionary(p => p.ID, p => p.Index);
            clients = clients.OrderBy(p => SortableIntDictionary[p.Id]).ToList();  And it crashes with error i mentioned though it is not required much. It failed on second line

Comment: @Moons It sounds like you have an ID in your list of `T` that doesn't appear in your sorting-list, hence my `Where` line in the second query.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, no need for comparer

```
 // Setup test data
 var orderList = new List<int> { 2, 1, 3 };

 var stuffList = new List<Stuff> { 
            new Stuff { Id = 1, Name = "Apple" },
            new Stuff { Id = 2, Name = "Banana" },
            new Stuff { Id = 3, Name = "Test" }
        };

 // Do sort according to list
 var result = orderList.Select(idx => stuffList.Where(s => s.Id == idx));
```

Edit: It may be faster to create an ID-lookup:

```
var stuffDictionary = stuffList.ToDictionary(s => s.ID, s => s);
var result = orderList.Where(idx => stuffDictionary.ContainsKey(idx))
                      .Select(idx => stuffDictionary[idx]);
```

Comment: This is actually a much better idea than mine, although I'd make an ID=>Stuff dictionary from `StuffList` to turn the `Where` into an O(1) equivalent.

Comment: @TommyGrovnes How does that look?